# Spring 5 webflux how to set a timeout to an existing Webclient

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux, reactor, reactor-netty

I have a WebClient bean defined in my configuration class. It involves a lot of configuration to its connector (including setting SSL, proxy, etc).

```
    @Bean
    @Primary
    @Scope("prototype")
    public WebClient webClient()
    {
       SslContextBuilder builder = SslContextBuilder.forClient();
        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient
                .create(ConnectionProvider.fixed("webClientPool", maxConnections))
                ...

        ReactorClientHttpConnector connector = new ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient);
        WebClient webClient = WebClient.builder()
                .clientConnector(connector)
                .exchangeStrategies(getExchangeStrategies())
                .build();
        return webClient;
```

In one of the beans that get this WebClient injected, I want to set different timeouts.

I thought to use `webClient.mutate().clientConnector(...)` method, but that would require me to set the whole configuration from scratch just for setting the timeouts. 
Unfortunately, WebClient and HttpClient don't have .getxxx() methods that could have helped me copying the old client configuration into the new one.

I want to have a way to set for the mutated WebClient only the timeout option of the tcp-client.
Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

according to the documentation

> WebClient.Builder mutate()
>
> Return a builder to create a new WebClient whose settings are replicated from the current WebClient.

Will return a new builder with all the previous settings set so you don't need to copy anything over.

[webclient mutate](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/reactive/function/client/WebClient.html#mutate--)

if you want to minimize configuration as much as possible you can:

define a `@Bean` where you configure as much as possible of the `HttpClient.Builder` as possible so you can autowire in the HttpClient.Builder later

Then you define 2 webclients that autowire in the httpclient and finish off the httpclient.build() into each webclient.

or you define one webclient and then in the class that needs the modified one you inject in the webclient, and the httpclient.builder and finish the configuration and mutate the webclient.

Comment: Thanks. I already thought of this technical solution, but I wanted to avoid this redundant Builder bean and find a more elegant solution, relying on the WebClient bean only.

Comment: Then please define what ”elegant” is instead of rejecting people answer due to ”taste”. That is the most elegant solution imho.

Comment: The ```WebClient``` construction uses ```HttpClient``` object, which uses ```.tcpConfiguration()``` call, which uses ```Function<TcpClient, TcpClient>``` consumer. In our project, this consumer configures the tcp client's timeouts and other values.

According to your purposed solution, we'll need to add 2 more beans: for the consumer, and for the ```HttpClient```. Then we'll have to inject those 3 beans, modify the consumer, build the ```HttpClient```, wrap it with ```ReactorClientHttpConnector``` and set it using ```WebClient.mutate().clientConnector(...)```.

Comment: What I was hoping to have is something like: ```Function<...> tcpConfigSetter = webClient.clientConnector().httpClient().tcpConfiguration();
/* set new timeouts for the tcpConfig here */
webClient = webClient.mutate()
        .clientConnector()
        .httpClient()
        .tcpConfiguration(tcpConfigSetter);
```

Comment: well as you have seen for yourself, tcpConfiguration is a function, and you need to redefine the entire function. So you are asking a question for something you already know the answer for, and you have already decided that, that is the only solution. So all i can say is, good luck with that!